# Use of unassigned local variable 'bar'

Tags: c#

Why if do this:

```
Object bar;
Foo(bar);
```

in C# I get a

```
Use of unassigned local variable 'bar'
```

error?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Assign some value to _bar_ (even null is fine)
Object bar = null;

Comment: You cannot do that in Java, either.

Comment: You can't do that in Java -- http://ideone.com/dy4vUh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about assigning a value to the variable before you use it, as the error message states.

If you are passing the variable to a method you might want to take a look at using [out keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee332485.aspx)

> The out keyword causes arguments to be passed by reference. This is
>   like the ref keyword, except that ref requires that the variable be
>   initialized before it is passed. To use an out parameter, both the
>   method definition and the calling method must explicitly use the out
>   keyword.

from the link you can see how to use the varaible if you wish to pass to a method and expect the variable to be initialised after that.

```
class OutExample
{
    static void Method(out int i)
    {
        i = 44;
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        int value;
        Method(out value);
        // value is now 44
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assign something to bar.

```
Object bar = new Object();
```

Or assign it null

```
Object bar = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "bar" has not been instantiated and therefore cannot be used. Just set it to null and C# will allow you to use it. C# does this to force the initialization of a variable before it can be used. Really, it's just good programming practice.

```
Object bar = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your variable before using it:

```
Object bar = null;
```

Initializing it to `null` will give the same as not-initializing but will make it usable. If you want an actual value/class-instance, try:

```
Object bar = new Object();
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign it a value:

```
Object bar = new Object();
```

Or

```
Object bar = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign value before use. null will work for object. default will work for any type.

```
Object bar = default (Object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have to assign `null` to the `bar`

```
Object bar = null;
```